# spring-ws-security dependency conflict

Tags: spring-ws, wss4j, opensaml, xmlsec

I'd like to use spring-ws-security in order to secure my web service with `Wss4jSecurityInterceptor` and signatures. But there is a dependency conflict which make this system unworkable. The `spring-ws-security:2.1.2.RELEASE` seems to be not workable as well.

```
spring-ws-security : 2.1.3.RELEASE [compile]
 - wss4j : 1.6.5                   [compile]
   - xmlsec : 1.5.1                [compile]
   - opensaml : 2.5.1-1            [compile]
     - openws : 1.4.2-1            [compile]
       - xmltooling : 1.3.2-1      [compile]
         - xmlsec : 1.4.4          [compile] (omitted for conflict with 1.5.1)
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, thanks, but it didn't work. Finally we refused the solution with spring ws security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is you are already including a the same dependency witha newer version
I think something in the lines of this would solve it. Add it to your spring-ws-security dependency declaration.

```
<exclusions>
     <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
          <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no problem here. `wss4j` has a direct dependency on `xmlsec` and it simply overrides the version of the transitive dependency. WSS4J is sufficiently tested to ensure that replacing 1.4.4 with 1.5.1 doesn't cause any issues in OpenSAML.